# Custom Yup validation for comparing 2 fields of Different Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

> formA.js

**All the Keys are mapped to a json with a field type on another .js file**

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const dateRegExp = /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;

const formA = {
  isArray: false,
  initialValues: {
      number: 0,
      email: '',
      details: {
        city: '',
      },
      isRouteUser: false,
      province: 'ON',
      gender: '',
      country: '',
      prelabel: 0,
      date: '',
      users: [
        {
          name: '',
          age: 0,
        },
      ],
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object({
    number: Yup.number(),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email('Invalid email address')
      .required('Email is required'),
    details: Yup.object({
      city: Yup.string().required('City is Required'),
    }),
    isRouteUser: Yup.boolean(),
    province: Yup.string(),
    gender: Yup.string(),
    country: Yup.string(),
    prelabel: Yup.number(),
    date: Yup.string().matches(dateRegExp, 'date should mm/dd/yyyy format'), // change to date validation
    users: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().required('user required'),
        age: Yup.number(),
      }),
    ),
  }),
};

export default formA;
```

> formB.js

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import formA from './formA';

const { validationSchema } = formA;

const formB = {
  isArray: false,
  initialValues: {
    phone: '',
    place: '',
    line11: 0,
    line12: 0,
    line150_1: 10,
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    phone: Yup.string()
      .required('This field is required')
      .min(6, 'At least 06 characters'),
    place: Yup.string().required('Place field is required'),
    line11: Yup.number(),
    line12: Yup.number().required()
   .moreThan( // connection between 2 keys on same schema
    Yup.ref('line11'),
    'Should be more than line11',
    ),
    line150_1: Yup.number().required('150 field is required'),
  }),
};

export default formB;
```

**The key on formA ("number") has a connection with Key on formB ("line11"). the number Should be always less than line11.**

**All the validation are done with Yup**

**The validation of Different keys on the same forms are working properly but the inter connection of the forms are not working .**

**
I tried to concat  the validation schema and worked with .when() function of yup it validated the form with out the connection from the other .**

**Any Idea??**

Answer (score 0):

```
const getValue = (object, keys) => keys.split('.').reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object);

function isValidLine12WithPrelabel(message, fieldId) {
  return this.test('is-valid-line-12-with-prelabel', message, function (value) {
    const { path, createError, from } = this;
    const dependentFormValue = getValue(from[1].value, fieldId);
    if (value === dependentFormValue) {
      return createError({ path, message: 'value of prelabel matching with this field' });
    }
    if (value > dependentFormValue) {
      return createError({ path, message });
    }
    return true;
  });
}

Yup.addMethod(Yup.number, 'isValidLine12WithPrelabel', isValidLine12WithPrelabel);
```

This works only if the two forms are object failed for array of object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).